# IN R: How can I count how many times a name appears in a column? I have one column with different names & I want to find out how many times each

Tags: r

I want to count how many times each name has appeared in that column. I tried a count() but it won't work for character type variables. How can I do this?

I want to get these counts so I can then make a bar graph from this info.

This information is being read into R from an Excel file.

Thank you, I am new to R.

Comment: Take a look at `?table`

Comment: Count works fine with character variabeles, `library(dplyr); count(your_data, name_column)`